# why singleton instance has to intialize in following code

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Singleton
{
public:
    static Singleton *getInstance(); 

private:
    Singleton(){}
    static Singleton* instance;
};

Singleton* Singleton::instance = 0;
Singleton* Singleton::getInstance() 
{
    if(!instance) {
        instance = new Singleton();
        cout << "getInstance(): First instance\n";
        return instance;
    }
    else {
        cout << "getInstance(): previous instance\n";
        return instance;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Singleton *s1 = Singleton::getInstance();
    Singleton *s2 = Singleton::getInstance();
    return 0;
}
```

i didn't understand why should singleton instance variable should be initilized with 0 in the following line.
Singleton* Singleton::instance = 0;
Because when i forgot to initilize the instance i got error as

```
singleton.cpp:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `Singleton::instance'
singleton.cpp:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `Singleton::instance'
singleton.cpp:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `Singleton::instance'
singleton.cpp:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `Singleton::instance'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Because it's the rules of C++. `static Singleton* instance;` is a declaration, but variables have to be defined as well, `Singleton* Singleton::instance = 0;` is a definition.

Answer (score 1):

`static Singleton* instance;` is a declaration and not a definition.

As per [[class.static.data]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mem#class.static.data-2)

> The declaration of a non-inline static data member in its class definition is not a definition...

So without the below line of code,

```
Singleton* Singleton::instance = 0;`
```

`instance` is not defined in the code. And trying to use it in `getInstance` will result in undefined reference errors.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the procedure to initialize a static member in C++, the only reason to initialize a singleton to null is because you explicitly need to initialize at a later stage in your application for some reason (like waiting for other resources to be allocated and/or initialized). Otherwise, it can be initialized during the static declaration. Furthermore, you dont need to deal with pointers to create a Singleton.

```
class Singleton
{
public:
    static Singleton & getInstance(); 

private:
    Singleton(){}
    static Singleton instance;
};

Singleton Singleton::instance;
Singleton & Singleton::getInstance() 
{
   return instance;
}
```

EDIT: Nevermind, I see your question was oriented towards the static initialization procedure rather than the pattern itself